# expo camera in react native is showing camera size of notification bar in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, camera, expo

1. though i have copied the exact sample code of expo-camera
   which is working fine but in my device it is not working.
   expo camera in react native is showing camera size of notification bar in mobile.
2. if you have more resources related to react native camera please share.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 20,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

[image]